# How to iterate over json response array

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a question about Gatling. 
I need to get the following response:

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Jack"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "John"
} 
]
```

grab those ids, iterate over them and make a new request for each of them.
So far I have this:

```
.exec(
            http("Image list")
                .get("/api/img")
                .headers(headers_0)
                .check(
                    jsonPath("$..id").findAll.saveAs("imgs")
                )
        )
```

It successfuly saves ids to "imgs" which is session variable but I am not able to iterate over them or process it at all.

How can I process it? I am new to Gatling and Scala so I have no idea how to approach this. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the `imgs` session variable as a Scala `List`:

```
val ids = session("imgs").as[List[Int]]
ids.foreach(id => ...)
```

*An update to reflect the fact that the internal implementation is now a `Vector`, as OP has discovered:*

```
val ids = session("imgs").as[Seq[Int]]
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: `i.g.c.a.b.SessionHookBuilder$$anon$1 - 'hook-1' crashed with 'java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Vector cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.List', forwarding to the next one`

Comment: found a solution but Thank You for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. 
The only possible format is `Seq`. In my case this solves the problem:

```
val imageIds = session("imgs").as[Seq[String]]
```